# Single speaker with 2 8ohm parallel inputs?

Tags: speakers, wiring

I just got a free Fender cabinet that only has one speaker, but looking at the back it has two separate inputs. They're labeled as 8ohm parallel, but I thought you needed at least two speakers to wire a cabinet in parallel.

Does this mean I can just use either one of the inputs and it will be 8ohms?

Comment: It's a throughput socket, wired in parallel. Wiring one will give 8 ohms, wiring 2 will give 4 ohms.

Comment: @Tetsujin, so if I only plug my amp into one input it's 8 ohms, but if I were to plug two amps into it, it would be 4 ohms for each?

Comment: no no no... one amp only. Potentially 2 identical speakers... though as you only have one, the point is moot.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I'm still somewhat confused. Why have two inputs for the one speaker if you're never supposed to use both? The cab was clearly built to have only the one speaker.

Comment: Orrr are you saying I can chain multiple cabinets if I had more than one? That would make much more sense

Comment: You don't want to plug two amps into any speaker!!   it's a strange one, but is probably an orphan, its twin got lost somewhere.

Comment: One amp, two speakers is what it was designed for. As Tim says, **never** two amps, one speaker.

Comment: I assumed that was a bad idea haha that's why two inputs had me confused. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly a Through connection, wired in parallel with the other socket.  Yes, you can use either socket as input.  If you connect through to a second, similar speaker, the amplifier will be seeing 4 ohms.   This won't worry a modern amplifier, though it might an older valve amp.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution - open up the cab., see how the jacks are wired - series, parallel, put a multimeter across the speaker to see if it is indeed 8ohms. Then you have the options.